# SQL - "Default" when creating a table - is it neccessary?

Tags: mysql, sql

Looking at examples of a standard SQL layout I see this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS siteUser (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;
```

What is th purpose of the "DEFAULT" at the end of specifying the engine? Is there any need for it? I tried to find an explanation of it on tutorial websites but I didn't have any luck.

James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to set ENGINE=InnoDB  as the default engine. So one way is to either remove the Engine = INNODB from your create table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS siteUser (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL
)
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb1093)

Or the other way which `GolezTrol` has suggested:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS siteUser (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT charset = utf8;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f17d7)

From the [Manual: InnoDB as the Default MySQL Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html)

> In previous versions of MySQL, MyISAM was the default storage engine.
>   In our experience, most users never changed the default settings. With
>   MySQL 5.5, InnoDB becomes the default storage engine. Again, we expect
>   most users will not change the default settings. But, because of
>   InnoDB, the default settings deliver the benefits users expect from
>   their RDBMS: ACID Transactions, Referential Integrity, and Crash
>   Recovery.

However if you want to make the INNODB as your deafult engine then there is one other way:

Under [mysqld] section in your ini file, add:

```
default-storage-engine = innodb
```

It is there in  `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: So you can only make Inno default by changing the ini, yet, you can also add `default` after a create table statement to make Inno default?

Comment: @GolezTrol:- Yes both will work. I just tried to give an alternative :)

Comment: I don't think the document you refer to says anything about a `DEFAULT` parameter. It just says, that since InnoDB is the default from 5.5, you don't need to specify an engine at all if you want to  use InnoDB. Or do I overlook something?

Comment: @GolezTrol:- Yes thats true. And I added that just to point that fact only that we dont need to add that explicitly from 5.5. Is that misleading?

Comment: So as long as my mysql version is after 5.5 I can delete this: ```ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT;```?

Comment: @JamesWillson:- Indeed! :)

Comment: I just meant that the `DEFAULT` keyword should not be there at all. Unrelated to the fact that MySQL switched default engines. You can change which engine is default in the inifile, but you cannot change it in a create table statement. Well, you can, but for the table only, and in that case it's not default at all. It's just the only engine for that table. See my answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol:- Yes got that. So I the doc which I added is correct and OP doesnt need to add any default engine. As it would by default point to INNODB. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb1093

Comment: Point is, OP asks about `DEFAULT` keyword, and your explanation of it is wrong. It's just a syntax error. The `engine=InnoDB` is clear. That's not what the question was about.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure it's not an error? I can't find any reference of a `default` parameter for the database engine in a create table statement. Also, your create table statement fails in SQLFiddle.com in both MySQL 5.1 and 5.5.

I think you might have misinterpreted the default as being part of the `engine` clause, while actually it was part of a `charset` or `collate` clause. For instance, this is valid, since `default` is an optional keyword in front of the charset clause:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS siteUser (
  id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  email varchar(64) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  password varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

I guess the `charset` and `collate` clauses can have the `default` keyword (which is practically meaningless by the way), because they specify a default charset or collation, but there is still a possibility to override this per column.

For a storage engine this would be silly. There is no 'default' storage engine for a single table. There is only one. Also, it wouldn't make sense if it would set the default for the whole database. Why would that be an option in a create table statement?